# sendAction on stack components, controller actions

Tags: ember.js, components

Is there a way to call controller action on stack components (nested hierarchy of components) via sendAction? For exemple, I have modal compoment with some buttons compoments and I would like exec an action on a controller who called. I haven't taken a look at the source yet. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Ember.Instrumentation http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Instrumentation.html

You can use it to send and register events on a more global level.

In my understanding using sendAction "only" bubbles up the hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

closure action is the answer for your question.

Define action in controller and send that action to component and you can use sendAction from component.

**app/controllers/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    controllerAction(){
      //
    }
  }
});
```

While including the my-component in application.hbs,

```
{{my-component controllerAction=(action 'controllerAction') }}
```

In `my-component.js`, you can just say `this.sendAction('controllerAction')` it will call controllers `controllerAction` method.